# Generate a heat map from CSV file using numpy and matplotlib - how to display negative numbers on axis

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib, graph

I would like to produce a heat map from CSV data that contain negative values in the x axis. I copied code from this post as a starting point: [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132499/plot-heat-map-from-csv-file-using-numpy-and-matplotlib). However, when I try it this does not display the negative x values. In fact, with some data sets (like the example) it doesn't appear to set the correct axis values at all. I am unsure why this is the case as the axis seem to be defined from the CSV data in the code. I thought it might be to do with `dtype=np.int` but it seems it is not.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv_file_path = '<FILE PATH>'


def get_xyz_from_csv_file_np(csv_file_path):
    '''
    get a grid of values from a csv file
    csv file format: x0,y0,z0
    '''

    x, y, z = np.loadtxt(csv_file_path, delimiter=',', dtype=np.int).T

    plt_z = np.zeros((y.max()+1, x.max()+1))
    plt_z[y, x] = z

    return plt_z


def draw_heatmap(plt_z):
    # Generate y and x values from the dimension lengths
    plt_y = np.arange(plt_z.shape[0])
    plt_x = np.arange(plt_z.shape[1])

    z_min = plt_z.min()
    z_max = plt_z.max() 

    plot_name = "plot"
    z_name = "Signal"

    color_map = plt.cm.rainbow 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    cax = ax.pcolor(plt_x, plt_y, plt_z, cmap=color_map, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max) 
    ax.set_xlim(plt_x.min(), plt_x.max())
    ax.set_ylim(plt_y.min(), plt_y.max())
    fig.colorbar(cax).set_label(z_name, rotation=270) 
    ax.set_title(plot_name)  
    ax.set_aspect('auto')
    plt.show()
    return figure
    figure = plt.gcf()
    plt.show()
    return figure   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fname = 'temp.csv'
    # create_test_csv(fname)
    res = get_xyz_from_csv_file_np(csv_file_path)
    draw_heatmap(res)
```

The output I get is this:

[image]

The example data file is a comma delimited csv with this data (x,y,z):

```
-2  -1  0
-2  0   10
-2  1   0
-1  -1  2
-1  0   5
-1  1   2
0   -1  0
0   0   0
0   1   10
1   -1  10
1   0   0
1   1   0
2   -1  10
2   0   0
2   1   10
```

Can anyone (1) fix this code so that negative values can be displayed an the axis are correct and (2) explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Never used `pcolor`, but from what I see, `plt_x` and `plt_y` are purely positive integers, because you created them using `np.arange()`, which should explain the color bar issue. And from your axis lims, it seems `plt_x = [0,1,2]` and `plt_y = [0,1]`

Comment: Also if you add a `print(plt_z)` what do you get?

Comment: Hi @JuanC If I add print(plt_z) I get: [[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [10.  0. 10.]]  (Sorry, not sure how to format comments!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below first mimics the `.csv`file with an array and then extracts `x`, `y` and `z`. To know the dimensions, not just the maximum but the difference between maximum and minimum need to be considered. The `x` and `y` arrays are only interesting for the rest of the code because of their minimum and maximum.

To draw the heatmap, only `plt_z` is needed, as it already has the correct shape. `x` and `y` can be used to set the extents (i.e. the values for the x and y axis). `plt.imshow()` is a similar function to `plt.pcolor()` but allows to set the extents as a parameter. It needs `origin='lower'` because for many image formats the origin is at the top.

To have the ticks in the center of the cells, an extra margin `0.5` needs to be added.  To have the ticks shown at every integer position, a [`MultipleLocator()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) can be used.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

def get_xyz_from_csv_file_np():
    data = [[-2, -1, 0],
            [-2, 0, 10],
            [-2, 1, 0],
            [-1, -1, 2],
            [-1, 0, 5],
            [-1, 1, 2],
            [0, -1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 10],
            [1, -1, 10],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [2, -1, 10],
            [2, 0, 0],
            [2, 1, 10]]
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.int)
    x = data[:, 0]
    y = data[:, 1]
    z = data[:, 2]
    n = y.max() - y.min() + 1
    m = x.max() - x.min() + 1
    return x.reshape(n, m), y.reshape(n, m), z.reshape(n, m)

def draw_heatmap(plt_x, plt_y, plt_z):
    plot_name = "plot"
    z_name = "Signal"
    color_map = plt.cm.rainbow
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    cax = ax.imshow(plt_z, cmap=color_map,
                    extent=[plt_x.min() - 0.5, plt_x.max() + 0.5, plt_y.min() - 0.5, plt_y.max() + 0.5], origin='lower')
    fig.colorbar(cax).set_label(z_name, rotation=270)
    ax.set_title(plot_name)
    ax.set_aspect('auto')
    # optionally force to have ticks at every integer position
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
    plt.show()

x, y, z = get_xyz_from_csv_file_np()
draw_heatmap(x, y, z)
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: In case the z-values have a natural order, it would be best [not to use the `rainbow` colormap](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/), but one of the ['Perceptually Uniform Sequential' colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) ('viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma', 'cividis').

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to make the "boxes" centre on the x/y values? For example, in your figure the x values are -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 but the boxes appear to be centred on -1.6, -0.8, 0, 0.8, 1.6. The same is true for the y axis.

Comment: Out of interest, why did you used dtype=np.int and not dtype=float? I found this caused problems with data with non-whole numbers. If there are no fractions in the data, is it faster/better to use np.int?

Comment: I used `dtype=np.int` to have the same format as the example code in the question. But in general, using float is the recommended way to go. Anyway, internally matplotlib will convert everything to floats. There is no speed advantage for using ints; ints are probably worse in this case. Ints are only recommended if you later want to use them explicitly as such, for example as indices into other arrays.